# cells of quotient CW complex

Tags: general-topology, geometry, homotopy-theory, homology-cohomology, simplicial-stuff

Let $X$ be a CW complex and $Y$ a CW subcomplex. If $X$ has no cell of dimension $n$, for some $n>0$, then $X/Y$ has no cell of dimension $n$. Is it true? Why?

Comment: do you know about local homology? or cellular homology?

Comment: There are two ways to interprete your question. If a "cell" means one of the defining cells of a CW complex, then the answer is immediate "by the very definition". If you mean "subspace of the underlying topological space of CW complex which is homeo to the n-cube, you should rewrite your question. The answer is still the same, but harder.

Answer (score 1):

Intuitively you can think about the quotient space of such a good CW pair $(X,Y)$, as collapsing all cells in $Y$ to a point. So if you collapse $Y$ you get all cells of $X$ which were not in $Y$ but glued in maybe a very different way than before. So the dimension (i.e. the highest dimension where there exists a cell) of the quotient space decreases at most.

So for a more rigorous attempt, note that all interiors of cells in $X/Y$ were already interiors of cells in $X$. So we conclude: on every cell which is not contained in $Y$ (those don't interest us, since they are collapsed to one single point) the quotient maps restricts to a homeomorphism on the interior. This determines the dimension of a cell: the dimension of the quotient CW space is bounded by the dimension of the original CW space.

Hope this helps